# Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms for homology without pairs of spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Say a functor $H\colon \mathrm{Top} → \mathrm{Ab}^ℤ$ satisfies the following set of axioms:

1. **Homotopy**: If maps $f \colon X → Y$ and $g\colon X → Y$ are homotopic, then $H(f) = H(g)$.
2. **Excision**’: If $T ⊂ X$ and $S ⊂ X$ are subsets of a space $X$ such that $\operatorname{cls} S ⊂ \operatorname{int} T$, then the inclusion $ι \colon (X\setminus S)  /\!/ (T\setminus S) → X /\!/ T$ induces an isomorphism $H(ι)$.¹
3. **Dimension**: For any one-point space $\star$,  $H(\star) = 0$.
4. **Additivity**: $H$ preserves all small coproducts.
5. **Exactness**’: If $T ⊂ X$ is a subset of a space $X$, then there’s a long exact sequence of graded abelian groups
   $$H[+1] (X /\!/ T) \overset{δ[+1]}→ H(T) \overset{H(ι)}→ H(X) \overset{H(π)}→ H(X /\!/ T) \overset{δ}→ H[-1](T),$$
   where $ι\colon T → X$ and $π \colon X → X /\!/ T$ are inclusions and $δ\colon H∘(–/\!/•) → H[-1]∘(•)$ is a natural transformation of functors $\mathrm{Top}^2 → \mathrm{Ab}^ℤ$.²³

Is $H$ then a homology theory? (Maybe in the sense that if $H' \colon \mathrm{Top}^2 → \mathrm{Ab}^ℤ$ satisfies the [usual Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg-Steenrod_axioms), then $\mathrm{Top} \overset{(–,∅)}→ \mathrm{Top}^2 \overset{H'}→ \mathrm{Ab}^ℤ$ satisfies these modified versions as well.)

---

¹,²:Here, for $A ⊂ X$, the “double quotient of $X$ by $A$” is defined as $X/\!/A := \operatorname{cone} (A → X)$.

³: Here, for $k ∈ ℤ$, $H[k]$ denotes $H$ postcomponed by the endofunctor $\mathrm{Ab}^ℤ → \mathrm{Ab}^ℤ$ which shifts the degree by $k$ (so e.g. $H_n[+1] = H_{n+1}$).